# XCode is it possible to list all used frameworks from all subprojects that projects has?

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to locate subprojects that are using sqlite3.dlib.

Maybe some script that would traverse all subprojects and print all frameworks that subprojects is using. Does something like that exists?

Comment: do you want explicitly generate a list?

Comment: Yes, list of frameworks every single subproject is using